# PHP str_replace replacing text in string that doesnt match

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, replace

Im trying to run a str_replace on a 'dynamic string' coming from a user.

But everytime my function is run, it seems to output the wrong thing and i can't figure out how to fix it.

So for instance, if `$payload['Name'] = 'this name'`

Then when the function returns the string turns into

```
this name Placethis name
```

What seems to be happening is that its also replacing the `Name` inside the `PlaceName` in the array.

My code is as follows;

```
function formatThis($payload)
{
    $description = '';
    if ( array_key_exists('Description', $payload) ) {
        $description = $payload['Description'];
    }

    $placeName = '';
    if ( array_key_exists('PlaceName', $payload) ) {
        $placeName = $payload['PlaceName'];
    }

    $dynamicString = "Name PlaceName"
    $template = str_replace(
        array("Name", "Description", "PlaceName"),
        array($payload['Name'], $description, $placeName),
        $dynamicString
    );

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the string actually replaces correctly to the description of the function. Its just not the behavior you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of useing `str_replace`, you should use `preg_replace', check the [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b64e1d4b70756ff389692265671c0b8d44baf39)

```
preg_replace(['/\bName\b/','/\bDescription\b/','/\bPlaceName\b/'], [$payload['Name'], $description, $placeName], $dynamicString);
```

Comment: While this might work, the problem at hand is a good example were placeholders usually have a special syntax like `{here}`  or `{%here%}`